# String 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss' was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, string, datetime, uwp

I have a string like below:

```
string expiredDate = "2026-05-24 18:54:55";
```

I want to convert it to `DateTime` format using the code below:

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(expiredDate, "dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But it didn't work and I get this error:

[image: error message]

I've also tried replacing it using

```
DateTime expiredDate = DateTime.ParseExact(expiredDate, "dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("id-id"));
```

but I still get the same error.

How to solve it?

Comment: Maybe you should try the format string you've provided in the title of the question .....

Comment: Now that you have a perfectly valid explanation, go back and read the exception message to see how it tells you *exactly* what is wrong and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned already you input date string does not match with the format provided in the parse exact method. To convert the string to DateTime you can do the following:

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(expiredDate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If you want to re-convert the DateTime object to string with your format you can then convert it to string as f

```
string myDateStr = myDate.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 3):

So why not

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(expiredDate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your format is not matching the expiredDate string.

```
string expiredDate = "24 May 2026 18:54:55"
```

This would match the format you have specified of

```
"dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"
```

Better yet, stick to the conventional format of:

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
```